# Swagger file with warning

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

Swagger file is working as expected with warnig.

```
{
  'swagger': "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "3.0",
    "title": "Sample Service",
  },
  "schemes": [ "http" ],
  "host": "sampleservice.azurewebsites.net",
  "paths": {
    "/": {
      "post": {
        "summary": "Sample service",
        "description": "sample service",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "Input",
            "in": "body",
            "description": "valid input",

            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "MainAttr-1": {
                  "required": [ "Attr-1" ],
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "Attr-1": {
                      "description": "Attr-1",
                      "required": true,
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Attr-2": {
                      "description": "Attr-2",
                      "required": false,
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "Attr-3": {
                      "description": "Attr-3",
                      "required": false,
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "Attr-4": {
                      "description": "Attr-4",
                      "required": false,
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "Attr-5": {
                      "description": "Attr-5",
                      "required": false,
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "MainAttr-2": {
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [ "Attr-1", "Attr-3", "Attr-5", "Attr-8" ],
                    "properties": {
                      "Attr-1": {
                        "description": "Attr-1",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Attr-2": {
                        "description": "Attr-2",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Attr-3": {
                        "description": "Attr-3",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "boolean"
                      },
                      "Attr-4": {
                        "description": "Attr-4",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "boolean"
                      },
                      "Attr-5": {
                        "description": "Attr-5",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                      },

                      "Attr-6": {
                        "description": "Attr-6",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Attr-7": {
                        "description": "Attr-7",
                        "required": false,
                        "type": "string"
                      },
                      "Attr-8": {
                        "description": "Attr-8",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "success"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Issue-1) Warning should be removed

Issue-2) Attr-3 in "MainAttr-2" is boolean type attribute and it is required. But when i am selecting 'false' from the dropdown, it is treating as invalid input. It treats only 'true' as valid input. (Any Boolean attribute which is required behaving like this)

Due this warning i am unable to deliver the code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the beginning, change `'swagger'` to `"swagger"`. JSON requires double quotes around strings.
2. Remove extra comma at the end of:

   ```
   "title": "Sample Service",
   ```
3. Remove the `required` attribute from ALL property definitions (`Attr-1` to `Attr-8`) and use the `required` list at the object level instead (under `MainAttr-1` and `MainAttr-2`).

   ```
           "MainAttr-1": {
             "required": [ "Attr-1" ],    <-- list the required properties in this array
             "type": "object",
             "properties": {
               "Attr-1": {
                 "description": "Attr-1",
                 "required": true,        <-- remove this 
                 "type": "string"
               },
   ```

Other than that your spec is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still i am getting same warning

Comment: Make sure to remove the `required` attribute from ALL properties (`Attr-1` to `Attr-8`) and leave it only at the object level (the lists under `MainAttr-1` and `MainAttr-2`).

Comment: Thanks Helen. Issue fixed